# Unable to open project in Visual Studio 2013 Pro - Marmalade Project

Tags: visual-studio-2013, project, marmalade

I'm unable to open `Marmalade MKB` Files in Visual Studio 2013 Pro, while my other class mates can with the exact same version of Visual Studio. I've tried multiple projects but unfortunately I'am unable to open any. I've already tried to reinstall Marmalade.

The error message I get is:

> Unsupported This version of Visual Studio is unable to open the
>   following projects. The project types may not be installed or this
>   version of Visual Studio may not support them.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may have set the mkb to be opened by visual studio as default instead of Marmalade.

So instead of Marmalade taking the mkb and turning it into a visual studio project and then opening it Visual Studio is just trying to open the .mkb file it doesn't understand.

Try right clicking on the mkb and choosing Open in Hub (or similar) from the context menu. You should be able to then open in IDE from there and have it open your project in visual studio. If you still get the same error then it means the problem is probably something else. If it works you'll have to stop visual studio being the default that will hopefully let marmalade take over again

Good Luck